# Filling object fields value at runtime falls under which design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, reflection

just having a question in mind so thought lets get the views from expert. it might be a silly question.

Actually i am using Reflection Mechanism to fill the some of the fields value of a class at run time. lets say i have a class A with 5 fields. i'll set the value of 2 fields at compile time but the remaining three fields value i'll set at run time.

So my question is that does it fall under some Design pattern?

Regards,
Mahendra Athneria

Answer (score 1):

This is very close to what [AutoFixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/) does. Its [internal architecture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Architecture) is basically just a big [Chain of Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

The [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern also comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer depends on the semantic of your class and object stored. It makes me think to strategy design pattern ( [strategy_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) where the context can hold a particular strategy object. Maybe this isn't your case.